# What is the difference between "amazed at" and "amazed by"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Good day to all!

Could you please explain me in which cases it's better to use a preposition *at* and in which we should use *by*?

- amazed at / amazed by
- astonished at /astonished by

Thank you in advance

Comment: The choice of 'by' emphasises agency (ie emphasises the person / animal / physical object / occurrence prompting the amazement; not necessarly a volitional agent). The choice of 'at' highlights the amazement, if anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Amazed at* would be used to describe amazement of a single instance of something.

*Amazed by* would be more likely to be used as a more general description of amazement.

> Julie was amazed/astonished at Ted's impromptu juggling display.
>
> Julie was amazed/astonished by Ted's juggling skills each time he displayed them.

There is a very subtle difference.

The first one would be used to indicate that Julie's amazement is caused by the juggling, whereas in the latter example Ted is causing Julie's amazement.